# Highcharts. Place tooltip on top of all items

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How to set up tooltip display on top of all elements? I need to assign coordinates so that the tooltip does not close the chart, but the top block closes the tooltip.

http://joxi.ru/L21PnlgTRPVxEm

http://joxi.ru/Q2KNJ4kiL5X61m

```
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qzmtp0bj/
```

Comment: can you able to add your code?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to move the alignment of your legend?

Comment: Added sample code. I can move the tooltip, but it overlaps with the top block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place a tooltip outside of a chart container, enable `outside` option:

```
tooltip: {
    outside: true,
    ...
}
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/casug0Lk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside

---

You can also create more space in a chart for a tooltip by setting `marginTop` property:

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 150
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wj2y98ns/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop